# Android:How to scale canvas to fit in desired size

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have created this class which extends View and draws a graph in Canvas. While drawing a graph I am considering actual screen height and width and it draws a graph according to that.

My problem is I am using this View as a widget in another activity with a desired size say 100 by 150..but the View class doesn't scale itself and only shows a clipped part of it not the graph. I know O have to do some calculation to fit this canvas into desired size but I have no clue how to do that..Any help would be great!!

Code where I am drawing graph is

```
   public class GraphPlotting extends View
    {
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{

    readPoints();
    Paint paint1 = new Paint();
    paint1.setColor(Color.rgb(0xFF,0xFF, 0xFF));
    paint1.setStrokeWidth(1.0f);

    Paint paint2 = new Paint();
    paint2.setColor(Color.rgb(0xFF,0xFF, 0xFF));
    paint2.setStrokeWidth(10.0f);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);

    canvas.drawLines(p,paint1);


}
    public void readPoints()
    {
          DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
      getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

          height = dm.heightPixels;
      width = dm.widthPixels;

           // drawing graph based on above dimension which in my case is 480 by 800

    }
```

xml Layout where I am using this View

```
    <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_below="@+id/btn_analyze"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:id="@+id/rlgraph"
 >
<com.aventusoft.mylynel.GraphPlotting

        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

 />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to fit my canvas with my Relative layout height and width and graph should visible in that area..currently its showing the View but only part of it..Graph is not visible at all..Please help me in calculation I need to do..

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste direct from one of my own classes which extends ImageView to draw a graph.  The idea is that you can put this into any layout.  The class takes care of it's own measurements.

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {

    widgetHeight = h;
    widgetWidth = w;

    if (sizeChangedObservers != null && sizeChangedObservers.size() > 0) {
        for (SizeChangedObserver observer : sizeChangedObservers) {
            observer.callback(w, h);
        }
    }

    updateIncrements();

}
```

The sizeChangedObservers just let's me notify other classes if the graph size changes, e.g. I have scale indicators on the X and Y axis.  updateIncrements() is where I figure out how many pixels each X and Y represents using the device screen resolution, graph size and DPI count.

Using this approach, the canvas will be whatever size it is and you don't care.  When you plot, you just use x * xPixels and y * yPixels which are the calculated pixels per value.

[EDIT]  Try reading this first http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Comment: So, your suggestion is that I should paste this code into my class(code I showed above) which extends the View and draws graph in onDraw method?

Comment: I actually dont understand where to apply this method?

Comment: Well, not copy/paste but override your onSizeChanged method in your View class and use the same technique.

Comment: I am new to android..I have been reading abt this method and know it is gng to be usefull but still have no idea how can I use it..little more help would be great!!